# Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

When I try to add a new method into a `mongoose.Schema`, i have an error

**Error**:

> Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Since i look for resolve this error, i read all similar issues on StackOverflow, add cursor:{} in my code, but  It still not working. What I did wrong?

MongoDB 3.1.10: mongoose 4.8.7: node 11.6.0

```
const storeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter a store name'
  },
  tags: [String],
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
 });

storeSchema.statics.getTagsList = function() {
  return this.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$tags' },
    { $group: { _id: '$tags', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { count: -1 } }
  ], {$cursor: {}});
};
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use the `aggregate` method on the model, for example `return this.model('Store').aggregate([ ... ])`?

Comment: @chridam that's what [`.statics` key](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html) stands for.

Comment: Database logic should be encapsulated within the data model. Mongoose provides 2 ways of doing this, methods and statics. Methods adds an instance method to documents whereas Statics adds static "class" methods to the Models itself.

Comment: `storeSchema.statics.getTagsList = function () {
  return this.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$tags' },
    { $group: { _id: '$tags', count: { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $sort: { count: -1 } }
  ]);
};
`It\`s works. the problem solved by reinstall mongoose (twice :) & `npm audit fix`